# APEX_JSON.PARSE. Parsing a JSON Array of String

Tags: json, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a JSON in the below format which I need to parse in PL/SQL (Oracle DB). I am using APEX_JSON package to do this.

```
[{
    "category": "New",
    "subcategory": [{
        "subcategoryName": "Refurb",
        "selectedFilter": ["BRAND", "SIZE"]
    }]
}]
```

I need to loop through the array values selectedFilter.
I have tried with below code. But I am not able to get the count or the values for the selectedFilter array.

```
arr_count:=apex_json.get_count(p_path=>'.');
    FOR i in 1 .. arr_count LOOP
    subcategory_count:=apex_json.get_count(p_path=>'[%d].subcategory',p0=>i);
        FOR j in 1 ... subcategory_count LOOP
            selected_filter_count := apex_json.get_count(p_path=>'[%d].subcategory[%d].selectedFilter',p0=>i,p1=>j);    
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('filter count is: ' || selected_filter_count);
        END LOOP;       
    END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution after some research. I had to pass the p_values parsed during the APEX_JSON parse call. So the code looks like below

```
apex_json.parse(p_values=>l_values, p_source=>json_clob);
arr_count:=apex_json.get_count(p_path=>'.',p_values => l_values);
    FOR i in 1 .. arr_count LOOP
    subcategory_count:=apex_json.get_count(p_path=>'[%d].subcategory',p0=>i,p_values => l_values);
        FOR j in 1 ... subcategory_count LOOP
            selected_filter_count := apex_json.get_count(p_path=>'[%d].subcategory[%d].selectedFilter',p0=>i,p1=>j,p_values => l_values);    
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('filter count is: ' || selected_filter_count);
        END LOOP;       
    END LOOP;
```